# Need Selenium framework common function for next element visibility

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Need Selenium framework common function for next element visibility.
I have a web application which takes a little longer time to load, and I am building a java Selenium automation framework for the same,
At present I am using:

`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("<xpath>")));`

But using it for each and every element, 
like once I click on element A, next will wait for element B to load, then click on element B, then wait for element C, then click on element C.

I want to eliminate the step of waiting for each element of need a common function that can be used to mitigate this.
 I am a newbie to selenium so a detailed explanation with code example would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ExpectedConditions` methods *are* the common way to do it.

Comment: Have made a separate base class for these common functions, so can someone please elaborate on how this can be done? If I just need to call the function from base class then would be fine or can also be handled for all lines of code as default which would be much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, it would be something like:

```
public WebElement waitForElement(WebDriver driver, String xpath) {
    return new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
            .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath)));
}
```

I've added a line to work around [NoSuchElementException](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException.html) which will occur if the element is not present in the page as [visibilityOfElementLocated](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) function assumes that the element is present in [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) and it will throw the aforementioned exception if the element is not there.

Another option is going for [Page Object Model Design Pattern](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Design+Patterns+-+Page+Object+Model)